# How to store array of ids in pivot table?

Tags: laravel

I have this category with his children in this array:

[image]

Now I have three tables first called `categories`, second `children`, and third is pivot table called `category_child` between first and second table

For My problem I need to store `category_name` (in above image) in `categories` table, then store `child_name` in `children` table, finally, store the id of `category_name` and the ids of `category_name` in `category_child`

relation in Category model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Child')->withTimestamps();
}
```

relation in Child model:

```
  public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category')->withTimestamps();
}
```

my controller code:

```
   $category = Category::create([
        'category_name' => $request->category_name,
    ]);

    foreach($request->child_name as $child){

        Child::create([
            'child_name' => $child,
        ]);
    }

    $category->children()->attach($child);

    return redirect()->back();
```

the problem in this link `$category->children()->attach($child);`

How can I store the ids of `children` that had added in pivot table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you missed the many to many relationships there since the child can't belong to many parents! Each child will have one parent, so the category should have many children but each child must belong to one category. I think so.

Anyway, try this:

```php
    $category = Category::create([
        'category_name' => $request->category_name,
    ]);

    $children_id = [];

    foreach($request->child_name as $child){

        $children_id[] = Child::create([ 'child_name' => $child ])->id;
    }

    $category->children()->attach($children_id);
```

Comment: Thanks man!! means this is wrong way to create category with his children?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the `children` in your pivot table directly it should be done automatically if you store it in your childrens table and have the proper relation to it.

You need to create a pivot table. The migration method may look something like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_child', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('child_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('child')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Your models need to have following relation:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: How can that?!!! and already do like you type in both of models but did not store in pivot table!!

Comment: @Ahmed what dou you mean?

Comment: pls check my update, I've these relations in models, but when I add the pivot table is empty even I add to both of tables!